# Required filed indicator does not show if label text is empty in Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Below snippet is a piece of Vaadin Flow code:

```
    ComboBox<String> shipmentStatus = new ComboBox<>();
    shipmentStatus.setPlaceholder("Shipment  Status");
    shipmentStatus.setId("shipmentStatus");
    shipmentStatus.setRequired(true);
    shipmentStatus.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
```

Because the label text is empty, the required indicator does not show. How can we make it show at left side? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're using the ComboBox's Placeholder for the purpose you should be using a Label for. This is an accessibility antipattern - a person using a screen reader will not get "Shipment status" announced when entering the field and thus they will be lost. You should always provide a Label for a field.

Comment: Thanks ollitietavainen. We will take your advice and add a label.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to take accessibility seriously, you need to provide an accessible label for the field.

A placeholder is not a replacement for a proper label. It’s better to either not use a placeholder at all (some users can confuse it for a filled-in value), or use it to show an example of the expected input (for example, a date pattern).

If you can’t show a visual label above/next to the field, you can set the `aria-label` attribute on the component:

```java
shipmentStatus.getElement().setAttribute("aria-label", "Shipment status");
```

In your case, I think it is be acceptable to set the same string as the placeholder, to indicate the purpose of the field for sighted users.

For the required field indicator, I believe you will have to recreate it manually since you are not using the built-in label. I would wrap the field in a horizontal layout and add an appropriately styled symbol/character after it. If you want to make it look like the default Lumo theme indicator, here are those styles: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/master/packages/vaadin-lumo-styles/mixins/required-field.js#L43-L55

Comment: Thank you. We will take your advice and add a label.